# Keep nodeJs server running while executing the rest of tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

im new to nodeJS and webdriveIO writing some webdriveIO tests i have two functions:
smsServer(); and startTest();

1- smsServer();

```
function smsServer(){
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.query.text);
});
app.post('/', function(req,res){
    console.log("Post");
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
app.listen(3000, function(req, res){
console.log('App listening on localhost:3000');
console.log("req: ",req);
console.log("res: ",res);
});
}
```

2- startTest();

    `just some Test WDIO`

i want to keep my server running to recieve some verification codes while the second function (tests) executing any help will be appreciated before my boss kills me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a solution that worked for me for this by using event-emitter so my server code will be:

```
'use strict';

const express           = require('express');
const bodyParser        = require('body-parser');

const app               = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log('received sms %s', req.query.text);
    process.emit('sms', req.query.text);
    res.send(200);
});

app.post('/', function(req,res){
    console.log('received sms %s', req.query.text);
    process.emit('sms', req.query.text);
    res.send(200);
});

module.exports = app;
```

so the rest of the app would be

```
// decribe('some description', function(){
// some test code ...
return when.promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            process.on('sms', (sms)=>{
                // some work here

                resolve();
            });

            // some other code

        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

lunch your app without kill a process or use forever. 
But, I think when you lunch your app the server must still running,

```
npm install forever
```

and after

```
forever start yourapp
```

Comment: the code doesnt run it gives me some warnings about --spinSleepTime and --minUptime  myscript file name wdio.conf.js, Thanks

Comment: after i googled it, forever is used to keep the script running continuously which was not the problem here the problem was keep small piece of code in a script running without being terminated, Thanks.